# Errors when importing "MatTableDataSource" from "@angular/material"

Tags: angular

I have installed:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

and tried to simply import the MatTableDataSource into my component, without using it:

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material";
```

I already get the following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts(79,22): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts(89,29): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts(103,23): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts(153,30): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(133,30): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/typings/observe-content.d.ts(33,22): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/typings/observe-content.d.ts(67,65): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts(40,106): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
```

My versions:

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.6
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 7.3.0
@angular/cli: 1.5.6
@angular/material: 7.3.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.40
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.27
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.50
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.6
@schematics/angular: 0.1.15
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.15
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Because I don't know howto analyse this, I am asking for help here :-)

Comment: what is the angular material version

Comment: I have added all versions to the question. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above package.json file it seems you are using angular 5 with angular/material 7 which would cause the issue for you.

Either downgrade the **`@angular/material`** package to the matching version ( or try upgrading angular to the 7 version

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue too, I installed same version of material like on angular

`npm install --save @angular/material@5.2.5  @angular/cdk@5.2.5`